# How can I find the position of one element in a sentence compared to a same element?

Tags: python

This sounds very strange, let me explain. I would like to know how i can find the positions of a word if it is shared by two different lists in python. For example:

```
a =[i,am,using,the,internet]
b =[are,you,using,a,desktop]
```

It should be able to tell me positions 2 (from the first list, it just happens that's the position of it in both if them). I can see if any words are shared but I don't know how to find the position:

```
if any(x in a for x in b):
```

Yet I cannot get this line to tell me the position of it. I know this is incredible simple, my friend is teaching me how to code.

Comment: `intersection = [x for x in a if x in b]` then you can iterate using `List.index()` to retrieve the index of the strings in your intersection list.

Comment: @MeetTitan Thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome; and welcome to Stack Overflow! Enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the intersections using sets:

```
intersections = set(a) & set(b)
```

Then you can find the positions using `list.index(element)`:

```
for intersection in intersections:
    index_a = a.index(intersection)
    index_b = b.index(intersection)
    # Do something with the indices
```

From the reference:

> `list.index(x)` Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an > error if there is no such item.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to replace the word 'using' in list b with the position it is in list a using some sort of loop to achieve it?

Comment: You could do `b[index_b] = index_b` for example, could you clarify?

Comment: @James_Progert, try `index = b.index("using")` then `b[index] = index`